# OpenModelica show result while still running simulation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is it possible for OpenModelica to monitor a variable while the simulation is still running? Something like the scope in Matlab Simulink. Currently I'm using OMEdit v1.12.0 and it only plots all the results at the END of the simulation. I'm a newbie with Modelica, I have searched but could not find anything useful.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46221933/8520615.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the new interactive simulation
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#interactive-simulation

Note that you need to download the latest nightly build since its not part of 1.12.

Adeel.